# Get folder in which the command was invoked in nodejs

Tags: node.js, gulp

I want to get the folder from which the command was invoked.

For example I am running `gulp taskname` and it calls on functions on bunch of other files but I need a reference to the folder from which gulp was invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're after the current working directory.  Node provides this as a function you can call on `process`.

`process.cwd()`

I can't mind read, but I interpret `cwd` as "current working directory."

http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd